# Few records are written to google sheet

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

i'm writing the records to google sheet using `google sheets api` in `python`. Few records are written to the google sheet perfectly and few are not being written at all.

Can anybody please help me in knowing why some records are not written to google sheets.

```
def write_reply_to_sheets(self, drive_service, parent_id, columns, values):
    page_token = None
    fileName = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")
    sheet_values = []
    found = False
    while not found:
        response = drive_service.files().list(
            spaces='drive',
            fields='nextPageToken, files(id,name,parents)',
            pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for f in response.get('files', []) :
            # Process change
            if f.get('name') == fileName and parent_id in f.get('parents',[]):
                spreadsheetId = f.get('id')
                found = True
                break
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
    if not found:
        file_metadata = {
            'name': fileName,
            'parents': [parent_id],
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
        }
        fileObj = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
        spreadsheetId = fileObj.get('id')
        sheet_values.append(columns)
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    service = self.get_service(SCOPES, {"serviceType": "sheets", "version": "v4"})
    sheet_values.append(values)

    body = {
        'values': sheet_values
    }
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range='A1:D2',
        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body=body).execute()
```

Expecting uniform behavior of writing records to google sheets

Comment: you should use [gspead](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), it is easy and light to use

Comment: I want to know why those records were not written to google-sheets is it because of these limits. This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.

Comment: yes, it can be due to resource exhaustion reason (generally because of 100 requests per 100 seconds), if possible you should add a relay after adding 20 or so records, however I can't quite understand by *If i try to write the record which was not written to sheet, then it's being written*

Comment: The process of writing the records to sheets is an automated one and if i try writing left over records manually by passing each records to the above function then are being written to the sheets.

Comment: maybe because when you are manually running the function it is other batch of 100 seconds, moreover, is the script throwing any error at you?
furthermore, I'd suggest you to check if the values are actually being passed append function call , so like instead of appending the values, check by print statement if the values are coming or not.

Comment: There is a line in your code `sheet_values.append(columns)` is the variable `columns` containing values? Is there any pattern considering which values are written and which not? If you think you could have hit some quota limits, be aware that are additional limits apart from Spreadsheets API (e.g. Drive API). You can consult the project executions to retrieve a possible error message and understand which limit you hit if you did.